# Correct XPath syntax does not return elements when the XML contains namespace prefixes

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

When using XML which does not contain namespace prefixes, xpath() works as I expect. When using XML which does contain namespace prefixes, xpath() consistently returns no elements. This is using Python 3.6.9.

Using the following XML contained in a file named energy_trunc.xml which has no namespace prefixes, things work as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xmlns:espi="http://naesb.org/espi" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <content>
    <id>urn:uuid:086ff935-dbd6-5d6d-9117-97b562eee078</id>
    <IntervalBlock>
      <interval>
        <servicePointId>6004632444</servicePointId>
        <serviceType>ELECTRIC</serviceType>
        <unitOfMeasure>kWH</unitOfMeasure>
        <secondsPerInterval>900</secondsPerInterval>
        <duration>65664000</duration>
        <start>1636693200</start>
      </interval>
      <IntervalReading>
        <timePeriod>
          <start>1636693200</start>
        </timePeriod>
        <readingQuality>ACTUAL</readingQuality>
        <value>6.8</value>
      </IntervalReading>
    </IntervalBlock>
  </content>
</entry>
```

Python script:

```
xml = etree.parse(r'./energy_trunc.xml')
r = xml.xpath('/entry/content/IntervalBlock/IntervalReading[timePeriod/start=\'1636693200\']/value')
print (r[0].text)
```

This returns an array of length 1 and prints '6.8' as expected.

Using the following XML contained in a file named energy_trunc_ns.xml which has namespace prefixes, things bork:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:entry xmlns:espi="http://naesb.org/espi" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <ns3:content>
    <ns3:id>urn:uuid:086ff935-dbd6-5d6d-9117-97b562eee078</ns3:id>
    <espi:IntervalBlock>
      <espi:interval>
        <espi:servicePointId>6004632444</espi:servicePointId>
        <espi:serviceType>ELECTRIC</espi:serviceType>
        <espi:unitOfMeasure>kWH</espi:unitOfMeasure>
        <espi:secondsPerInterval>900</espi:secondsPerInterval>
        <espi:duration>65664000</espi:duration>
        <espi:start>1636693200</espi:start>
      </espi:interval>
      <espi:IntervalReading>
        <espi:timePeriod>
          <espi:start>1636693200</espi:start>
        </espi:timePeriod>
        <espi:readingQuality>ACTUAL</espi:readingQuality>
        <espi:value>6.8</espi:value>
      </espi:IntervalReading>
    </espi:IntervalBlock>
  </ns3:content>
</ns3:entry>
```

Python script:

```
xml = etree.parse(r'./energy_trunc_ns.xml')
r = xml.xpath('/ns3:entry/ns3:content/espi:IntervalBlock/espi:IntervalReading[espi:timePeriod/espi:start=\'1636693200\']/espi:value', namespaces={'ns3': 'http://namespace.com/ns3', 'espi': 'http://naesb.org/espi'})
print (r[0].text)
```

This returns an array of length 0 and (of course) prints nothing.

Running both of these examples through an online XPath test tool verifies both as working correctly.

Comment: https://lxml.de/4.2/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes

Comment: Been there and done that. Perhaps if you see something specific in that doc that applies to this case you might be so kind as to point me to it. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris, you forgot the namespaces: `r = root.xpath('/ns3:entry/ns3:content/espi:IntervalBlock/espi:IntervalReading/espi:value', namespaces= {'espi': 'http://naesb.org/espi', 'ns3': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'})`

Comment: @Hermann12, more specifically: I had the incorrect namespace for 'ns3.' Your comment fixed the problem nicely! A thousand thanks! I wish the question were not closed so that you could post this as the answer and I could mark it so.